# Using gaetestbed within virtualenv

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, nose, nosetests, gaeunit

I'd like to give GAE Testbed a try, but am running into the following error after completing the [instructions on its homepage](http://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed).

```
$ nosetests --with-gae
...
ImportError: No module named dev_appserver
```

I've confirmed that this happens in both a *virtualenv* and outside of one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resolved by adding `google_appengine` directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `--gae-lib-root` option as in

```
$ nosetests --with-gae --gae-lib-root=/opt/my/google_appengine
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved with these parameters:

- `--with-gae`
- `--gae-lib-root="C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine"`

**No backslash** at the end of the GAE path and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved on Linux by creating a sym link to the directory the plugin expects to find google-appengine, which is `/usr/local/google_appengine` .  It's mentioned briefly at the top of the overview on this page here: http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/

```
 sudo ln -s /home/username/google_appengine /usr/local/google_appengine
```